Stripe unkown error
I have a Stripe unkown error on my site.
Also if you click the pay later radio button, you can't go back to the stripe field...
I previously had the same issue that was exposed here (#48849), but I got rid of it by desactivate CiviContibute and reactivate it...

I think you are using single quote in a thousand separator which is causing a JS issue.
Can you check and update Thousands Separator in CiviCRM >> Administer >> Localization >> Languages, Currency, Locations

Wow you are my hero! It was that. Stripe works! I still don't know why if you choose the option to pay later, and then change back to pay with stripe, you don't have the stripe filed coming back...

there was a js error
